# Cast object to WebControl based on Switch enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure if this is possible in C#:

I have a `userControl` in which I have a property `inputType` - enum'd to have 3 possible options, textBox, dropDownList or checkBox.

I'd then like to create a new object of that type and add it to a placeholder in the userControl:

I can do this:

```
object txt;
    switch (_inputType)
    {
        case code.enums.inputType.textBox:
            txt = new TextBox();
            break;
        case code.enums.inputType.dropDownList:
            txt = new DropDownList();
            break;
        case code.enums.inputType.checkBox:
            txt = new CheckBox();
            break;
    }
```

However, then I can't access the properties of the textbox, dropdownlist or checkbox as Visual Studio doesn't know the type - Nor can I cast the object - `(TextBox)txt` -as I don't know which one it'll be...

Is there a way to do this? Or should I look to do all control specific operations in the `switch`?

As requested, ideally I'd like the `object txt` to be available for the rest of the page. So after the switch statement to be able to access `txt`.

I'll definately want to do:

```
plcHolder.Controls.add(txt);
```

That part is fine - it's just trying to access the control specific properties before that... Which I think it can't be done... But always best check with the SO experts :)

Many thanks,
Mark

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are consuming the results of the switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with .net 4.0framework you can use a `dynamic` variable

```
dynamic txt;
    switch (_inputType)
    {
        case code.enums.inputType.textBox:
            txt = new TextBox();
            break;
        case code.enums.inputType.dropDownList:
            txt = new DropDownList();
            break;
        case code.enums.inputType.checkBox:
            txt = new CheckBox();
            break;
    }
```

After this you can get its type of control ..
or you can use directly 
like

```
string boo = txt.Text;
```

or 
if you want to used as checkbox

you can use

```
bool checked = txt.Checked;
```

for read about dynamic variable go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Dynamic variables are a new one on my and fortuneately working with .NET 4.0 - You do need a level of bravery around them clearly!!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify object txt with `WebControl txt` in order to access common properties

And you cast to specific type if you wish adjust specific properties.

```
    //You declare as global variable of your class        
    public WebControl control{get;set};

    ....
    //Your code inside method
    switch (_inputType)
    {
        case code.enums.inputType.textBox:
            control= new TextBox();
            //Here you can set global property
            control.Id = ""; //etc.
            break;
        case code.enums.inputType.dropDownList:
            control= new DropDownList();
            break;
        case code.enums.inputType.checkBox:
            control = new CheckBox();
            break;
    }


//For Specific property

var test = (TextBox)control;
//Add specific property.
```

Comment: How would I access `result` outside of the switch statement?

Comment: you declare you control outside of swith, as global variable and you access , but if you wish accee properties you cast your property

Comment: I do like this, and the option of having a public property meaning it could be access from outside the UserControl could also prove useful. Thank you.